# Rails Foundation Orbit is not a function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I'm trying zurb foundation framework for the first time. I would like to create a slideshow; however, I receive type error orbit is not a function.

This is my application.js file:

```
 //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.core
//= require foundation
//= require active_admin
//= require contractor_validate
//= require painter_validate
//= require jquery.social.media.tabs.1.6
//= require jquery.validate.min
//= require payment
//= require the-tooltip
//= require general
//= require_self

$(document).foundation();

$(window).load(function() {
$('#featured').orbit();
});
```

Here is my application.css file:

```
  *= require active_admin
  *= require dcsmt
  *= require foundation_and_overrides
  *= require style
  *= require the-tooltip
  *= require jquery.ui.all
  *= require_self
```

Here's what the html/code looks like:

```
 <div class="large-6 columns">
        <div id="featured">
          <% count = 0 %>
          <% @slides.each do |s| %>
              <% if count == 0 %>
                  <%= image_tag s.slide_photo.url(:medium) %>
              <% else %>
                  <%= image_tag s.slide_photo.url(:medium) %>
              <% end %>
              <% count = count + 1 %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Please advise.

Update:

```
  group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

 # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
 # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
 gem 'zurb-foundation', '~> 4.0.0'
 end
```

Comment: Are you using the gem `zurb-foundation` (https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails)? This seem to be a Javascript issue, could you put the views HTML instead (not the `erb`) and what files //= foundation imports?

Comment: Put the views not erb?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5170679

Comment: Having the same problem here. Kinda silly. It seems to need special markup. The slider activates, but everything disappears and I get the error in the console.

Comment: I guess I'll continue to use bootstrap

Comment: Hey @Brian make sure you're loading the css files for orbit. I've seen where people would replace application.css with application.scss and do imports rather than using sprockets directives. I got it to work, however I still get an error saying missing object.

Answer (score 0):

If you run into this problem using the rails gem follow this article:

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html

You simple have to add data-orbit to your html:

```
 <div data-orbit>

 </div>
```